# How to get global error variable in ejs when fetching post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

My tech stack in this project: Express.js, node.js, mongodb + mongoose and ejs.

Problem: When i'm using fetch to send data to database and upload files instead of traditional send form throw submit button i have problem to show error messages. When i was using traditional way there was no problem because express render view and send variable error to this actual view:
`res.render('pages/projects/projects', { errors: e.error });;`
Problem comes out when i send data throw fetch. Of course i get response from backend with those errors in json but i don't even know how use those errors. In ejs file i check if there is error variable and when there is it show each error in form but if i send data throw fetch there is no "errors" variable and errors don't appear.

My goal: I wanna take those data errors from backend response and take it to this "errors" global(?) variable to show those errors in form.
So: I click button -> send data and upload files -> if something wrong get response with errors data -> show errors in form
OR second scenario with refresh page: I click button -> send data and upload files -> if something wrong get response with errors data -> refresh and send errors to same view -> show errors in form

I have form in ejs looking like this:

```
<%- contentFor('content') %>

<div class="uk-container uk-container-xsmall">
    <h3 class="uk-margin-medium-top"><%= __('navbar.projectsAdd') %></h3>
    <% if (errors) { %>
        <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-top" uk-alert>
            <div class="alert-icon alert-icon-danger"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">error</span></div>
            <p><%= __('form.error') %></p>
        </div>
    <% } %>
        <form method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="uk-card-box uk-margin-top">
                <div class="block">
                    <label>
                        <span class="uk-form-label"><%= __('form.title') %></span>
                        <!-- Using form state modifers, the classes can be identical for every input -->
                        <input value="<%= form.title %>" type="text" placeholder="<%= __('form.title') %>..." name="title" id="co" class="uk-input <% if (errors?.title) { %> uk-input-danger <% } %>"/>
                        <% if (errors?.title) { %>
                            <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove-top" uk-alert>
                                <p><%= __('errors.projects.slug.minLength') %></p>
                            </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="block uk-margin-top">
                    <label>
                        <span class="uk-form-label"><%= __('form.slug') %></span>
                        <!-- Using form state modifers, the classes can be identical for every input -->
                        <input value="<%= form.slug %>" type="text" placeholder="<%= __('form.slug') %>..." name="slug" class="uk-input <% if (errors?.slug) { %> uk-input-danger <% } %>"/>
                        <% if (errors?.slug) { %>
                            <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove-top" uk-alert>
                                <p><%= __('errors.projects.slug.minLength') %></p>
                            </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="block uk-margin-top">
                    <label>
                        <span class="uk-form-label"><%= __('form.client') %></span>
                        <!-- Using form state modifers, the classes can be identical for every input -->
                        <input value="<%= form.client %>" type="text" placeholder="<%= __('form.client') %>..." name="client" class="uk-input <% if (errors?.client) { %> uk-input-danger <% } %>"/>
                        <% if (errors?.client) { %>
                            <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove-top" uk-alert>
                                <p><%= __(errors?.client.message) %></p>
                            </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="block uk-margin-top">
                    <label>
                        <span class="uk-form-label"><%= __('form.description') %></span>
                        <!-- Using form state modifers, the classes can be identical for every input -->
                        <textarea value="<%= form.description %>" rows="5" type="textarea" placeholder="Opis projektu" name="description" class="uk-input <% if (errors?.description) { %> uk-input-danger <% } %>"></textarea>
                        <% if (errors?.description) { %>
                            <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove-top uk-margin-remove-bottom" uk-alert>
                                <p><%= __(errors?.description.message) %></p>
                            </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card-box uk-margin-top">
                <div class="block">
                    <label>
                        <span class="uk-form-label"><%= __('form.tools') %></span>
                        <!-- Using form state modifers, the classes can be identical for every input -->
                        <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-row">
                            <input id="skillsInput" type="text" placeholder="<%= __('form.tools') %>..." name="skillsInput" class="uk-input" />
                            <button type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-secondary uk-margin-left" id="skillsButton">
                                DODAJ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-flex uk-margin-small-top uk-badges-container">
                        </div>
                        <% if (errors?.tools) { %>
                            <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove-top uk-margin-remove-bottom" uk-alert>
                                <p><%= __(errors?.tools.message) %></p>
                            </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <!-- INPUT FOR TOOLS DATA -->
                <input id="toolsInput" type="hidden" name="tools" />
                <!-- INPUT FOR URL -->
                <!-- <input id="photosUrl" type="hidden" value="random" name="photosUrl" /> -->
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card-box uk-margin-top">
                <!-- <input type="file" name="photos" class="uk-input" multiple /> -->

                <div class="js-upload uk-placeholder uk-text-center">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">file_upload</span>
                    <span class="uk-text-middle"><%= __('form.upload') %></span>
                    <div uk-form-custom>
                        <input type="file" name="photos" onchange="filesFromInput()" id="photos" multiple>
                        <span class="uk-link"><%= __('form.uploadSelect') %></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <progress id="js-progressbar" class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100" accept="image/*" hidden></progress>
                <div id="preview" class="images-preview" uk-sortable="handle: .image-handler; threshold: 1; animation: false"></div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-margin-medium-bottom uk-margin-top" id="projectButton">
                <%= __('navbar.projectsAdd') %>
            </button>
        </form>    
</div>
```

In the same file i have also fetch to send all data to backend:

```
[...]

    form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        const photos = formData.getAll("photos");
        formData.delete("photos")

        formData.append('photosUrl', document.querySelector("[name='slug']").value)
        formData.append('title', document.querySelector("[name='title']").value)
        formData.append('slug', document.querySelector("[name='slug']").value)
        formData.append('client', document.querySelector("[name='client']").value)
        formData.append('description', document.querySelector("[name='description']").value)
        formData.append('tools', document.querySelector("[name='tools']").value)

        photos.forEach((e) => {
            formData.append("photos", e)
            formData.append("rawData", '/uploads/' + document.querySelector("[name='slug']").value + '/' + e.name)
        })

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/<%- lang %>/projects/create', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            redirect: "follow"
        })
        .then((response) => { response.json();})
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }) 

[...]
```

Backend looks like:

```
    async createProjects(req, res) {
        const images = req.files;

        const createdir = () => {
            const dir = path.join(__dirname, '../../public/uploads/' + req.body.photosUrl);
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(dir);
            }
        }
        const upload = () => {
            images.forEach((e) => {
                const newpath = path.join(__dirname, '../../public/uploads/' + req.body.photosUrl + '/' + e.originalname);
                fs.writeFileSync(newpath, e.buffer);
            })
        }

        try {
            await Projects.create({
                slug: req.body.slug,
                title: req.body.title,
                client: req.body.client,
                description: req.body.description,
                tools: req.body.tools,
                photos: req.body.rawData.join(',')
            })
            await createdir();
            await upload();
            res.redirect("/" + req.params.locale + '/projects')
        } catch(e) {
            res.status(500).send({ errors: e.errors })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is a little goofy in that an error typically doesn't throw.  If you're sending errors as JSON, what I'd probably do is:

```
 .then((response) => {
     if (!response.ok) {
         throw(response.json());
     }
     return response.json();
 })
```

```js
const fetch = async () => {
    return {
        ok: false,
        json: async () => {
            return {
                errors: ['some error']
            }
        }
    }
}

(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('sumeurl')
    try {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw await response.json()
      }
      return await response.json();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }

})();
```

and then you're `.catch` will actually get called

Comment: FYI, `throw` isn't a function.  It would normally be written without parens as `throw someValue`, not `throw(someValue)`.   `throw response.json()` does not make much sense because `response.json()` returns a promise.  It should probably be something more like `throw new Error(\`http request failed with status ${response.status}\`)`.

Comment: It's not what i want. I mean the response from backend i have but i didn't know how to take those errors and check if they exists like i do before `<% if (errors?.title) { %> ............ <% } %>`. Anyways i found i think better solution. I recreate all frontend logic and i dont use right now fetch but all extra data i put on input type hidden so when i traditional send form i can easily take all data in backend and express.js run `res.render('pages/projects/projects', { errors: e.error });` so after sending form errors appears like they should. I don't know if its safety but it works